# Discord.py Rewrite, Audit Log, How do I make it mention the channel the message was in?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been working on an audit log on discord.py bot. I'm stuck on how to mention the channel a message was edited in. Example: User edits message in #general, how do I make my bot get the channel ID of the message that user edited.
I wanted the embed to reference who edited the message, before and after, and what channel the message was edited in.

This is what I have currently:

```
class Log(Cog):

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print("Bot is online.")

@Cog.listener()
async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
    if not after.author.bot:
        if before.content != after.content:
            embed = Embed(title="Message Edited",
                          description=f"Edit by <#{after.author.display_name}>",
                          color=after.author.color,
                          timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

            fields = [("Before", before.content, False),
                      ("After", after.content, False),
                      ("Channel", "<#{CHANNEL ID}>", False)]  # This is the part I'm stuck on

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

            logchannel = self.bot.get_channel(798623500641894461)  # logs channel

            await logchannel.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Log(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `before` and `after` are [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message_edit#discord.Message) objects, you can access the channel attribute by typing either `before.channel` or `after.channel`. Here's a short example :

```py
@Cog.listener()
async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
    channel = before.channel
    logchannel = self.bot.get_channel(798623500641894461)

    await logchannel.send(f'Message edited in {channel.mention}'
```

For this kind of questions, you can look at `discord.py` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Reference : [`discord.on_message_edit(before, after)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message_edit#discord.on_message_edit)

Answer (score 0):

I recently replied to an issue someone had with this here is what I said this is working as of 08/06/2021.

Updated in line with the advice provided.

Here is the working code outlined in the previously linked article.

```
    @client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(message.author.name),
                          description="", color=0xFF0000)
    embed.add_field(name=message.content, value="This is the message that he has deleted",
                    inline=True)
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    await channel.send(channel, embed=embed)


@client.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before.author.name),
                          description="", color=0xFF0000)
    embed.add_field(name=message_before.content, value="This is the message before any edit",
                    inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=message_after.content, value="This is the message after the edit",
                    inline=True)
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    await channel.send(channel, embed=embed)
```

I hope this is better reading and helps whoever may need it.